# Tag merge/synonym request

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[validationengine](/questions/tagged/validationengine) and [jquery-validation-engine](/questions/tagged/jquery-validation-engine) both have approximately the same number of questions.

Based on the names of the tags, I believe that the first tag should be merged into the second where we keep [jquery-validation-engine](/questions/tagged/jquery-validation-engine).

I don't have the rep to do anything more than make this request.  And with ~65+ questions tagged on both, I'm not manually editing the questions.

Answer (score 3):

65+ questions to retag is not that much.

I've retagged them and also [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1810848) [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1810849) for the [jquery-validation-engine](/questions/tagged/jquery-validation-engine) tag to add more information.

Comment: +1 for the effort.  I suppose that depends on how you like to use up your mouse finger.  65+ was a little too tedious for me.  ;)